# Swichable date selectors

Tags: datetimepicker

I am creating a planner for my reporting system, the scheduling part consists of 3 parts

- The Execution plan. How often the report will be generated (hourly, 2 hours, daily etc)
- Start date. When the first report will be generated. If empty it will generate one immediately
- End date. When the report will stop been generated. If empty it will be generated forever.

[image]

Since the two dates, start and end, are `nullable` I have used a checkbox to show or hide the date inputs.

If the checkbox is not set I display a message `Start/end date is not set` and if the checkbox is set then i show the date input.

I am worried that the message doesn't help the user to understand that if she wants to set a date she have to click on the checkbox.

Please provide some ideas of a better title for the disabled state or another way of displaying nullable date selectors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a clickable area with the call to action text 'Set start date'. I think this is better than a status text, e.g. 'Start date not set'.
[image: Nullable datetime UI empty]

When the user click on this call to action the checkbox is set and the datetime selector is opened

[image: Nullable datetime UI selected]

When the date is set and the user clicks on the set checkbox then the UI returns to the first form of null datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, as date and time is selected specifically, I would strongly suggest changing the field header from 'start date' 'end date' (maybe to 'start' and 'end'. I hope you got my point).

Secondly,

- "If empty it will generate one immediately"
- "If empty it will be generated forever"

As this is the case for null states,

[image]

For start date field: Placeholder could be dynamically set to current date + time combination. It changes with live time.

For end date field: Placeholder could be set as forever.

Comment: I need the `null` part to be explicit from the user's actions. I need to know if the user has selected a date even if it's the current moment. The forever part is not very helpful either because there is not a valid datetime selection and thus if the user selects a date she can't go back to forever.

Comment: No. The 'current moment' and 'forever' placeholders appear whenever the user deletes or sets null in the Start and End fields. Therefore if the user sets 5th Feb 2018 in End field. Then s\he could go back to forever by just deleting it.
.
.
Also, you could add a "[ ] Forever" checkbox in the date picker.